# Nuitka failing to detect gcc version while cmd detects it

Tags: python, gcc, nuitka

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7gRP.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ylba.jpg)

My CMD detects gcc but my Nuitka installed in a venv does not. firstly it was not detecting even in CMD but I added it in PATH and it started detecting. I tried in Pycharm and VSCode.

I've no idea why it happens. I'm a beginner in python, if you need more info, just ask me with instructions, specially if i have to do some command to get this info.

Answer (score 0):

i had similar issue, all i had do was to ensure i add msvc through vs installer and restart my computer it automatically detected the compiler.